# Apache control in multi site server configuration

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualhost

I have an ubunto vm running a lamp stack, and a for now, one domain name redirecting to the vm's ip address.
Concept wise the main principle is I want users to register an account and get a "website" running over on a subdomain of my own domain. That part is easy with wildcard subdomains in apache vhosts etc and with certbot i managed to automatically have all subdomains protected under ssl.

Now, if a customer wants to buy his/her own domain name, with me or some other registrar they need to point an A record to my ip address and a CNAME from www to the domain name. And in my end I need to add a vhost file under sites-available folder configuring the virtual host file for that new domain name and restarting "gracefully" apache.

Here lies the problem. How can I manipulate apache vhosts files etc so I can accomplish this at the push of a button on my main website? I'm using PHP in my backend and doing it in php (shell exec etc) seems like a security risk..

Im running on GCP so any of GCP's services are available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Preconfigured multi site vhost will solve your problem I think. Please check this link( 
https://serverfault.com/questions/326130/dynamically-configured-mass-virtual-hosting ). Is this answer your query?

Comment: @AghilanB Preconfigured vhost works as long as i my customers use a subdomain on my domain like store1.mydomain.com. What im asking is how can dynamically reconfigure apache so that if a customer buys a domain like hisstore.com i can redirect that domain to the correct folder.
I can do this manually buy adding a new vhost config file (:80 and :443) and then restarting apache but i would like to know if theres a way to do it through php or some other language so the system would update itself as the customer pushes a button on a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Enabled mod_macros in apache;

```
sudo a2enmod macro
```

Added a macro for creating a http :80 virtual host and another for creating a https :443 virtual host with the necessary variables;

```
<Macro ProtectedVHost $domain>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@email.com
        ServerName $domain
        ServerAlias www.$domain

        DocumentRoot /var/www/customer_sites/$domain/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName $domain
            ServerAlias www.$domain
            ServerAdmin admin@email.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/customer_sites/$domain/public_html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
</Macro>
```

Created a conf file out of my public_html folder on my main websites editable in php where i add records using my own macro as the user adds in his domain:

```
Use {Macro Name} {Domain Name}
```

Import that file into apache.conf

Finally i created a CRON that starts ever so often and reads that file and compares it to a saved version. If the files has changed, it will gracefully restar apache which will read and re-create the necessary virtual hosts.

Hope this helps anybody looking to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about a shell script in your server you can run an application using SSH from a different machine; It can be a small instance that an application can be something like a putty which is available only on windows. You should find something relevant for Linux as there are many alternatives available. Use SSH client application and Python language to automate it.

As the manual process involves running the same command multiple times you can create virtual host  files and see if files are created in sites-available directory etc.

Once the new users register for your service you need to create virtual host files and run chown commands and see if the files are created in the sites from the directory and restart your apache. You can refer to the steps in Automating [virtual host setup on your server](https://dev.to/shriaas2898/automating-virtual-host-setup-on-your-server-4oha).